# Split long image over two pages

Tags: latex

I would like to know what the best way is to split a long image over two pages in latex.
Since it is for a scientific journal I am not really allowed to use external packages.
My idea is currently to create two separate images and add them in latex, with only the last one getting the caption and the first one not included in the numeration.
Is there any way to force the two images to stay close together and not allow any text to be inserted inbetween them? I don't mind having the images placed in some random location but they should obviously not get separated.
Looking forward to some advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I figured out how to do it, based on other answers I found here on stackoverflow:
[ContinuedFloat, and Subfloat](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15647/continuedfloat-and-subfloat)
[Page Break between images of a figure](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/245689/page-break-between-images-of-a-figure)

`\phantomcaption`is from the package `subcaption`.
`\ContinuedFloat`is from the package `caption`.

```
\begin{figure*}
    \centering
        \includegraphics[trim={0 41cm 0 0},clip,width=\textwidth]{Images.png}
    \phantomcaption
\end{figure*}

\begin{figure*}
\ContinuedFloat
    \centering
        \includegraphics[trim={0 0 0 64cm},clip,width=\textwidth]{Images.png}
    \caption{Lorem Ipsum}
    \label{FIG}
\end{figure*}
```

Comment: The two links are pointing to the same page "Page Break between images".
Could you post the full solution with the definitions (or source packages) of `phantomcaption` and `\ContinuedFloat`, please?

Comment: Fixed it. I hope it helps you out.